# nth moment, for 0 < n < 1 or n <0, do they exist?

Tags: mean, moments

I am interested in the moments, we have for instance the mean, $\mathrm{E}(X)$ and $\mathrm{E}(X^2)$. What about values like $\mathrm{E}(X^{1.5})$ or $\mathrm{E}(X^{-1})$? Have they been investigated?

Comment: Stuart & Ord, in *Kendall's Advanced Theory of Statistics* (Fifth Ed.), section 3.26, discuss such moments and provide references.  They show how to obtain negative and fractional moments of positive distributions from their moment-generating functions (provided those are defined for all non-positive arguments). One reference discusses relationships between fractional moments and fractional derivatives of the characteristic function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, investigated to at least some extent, as is readily seen by googling 'inverse moment' or 'fractional moments'.

Edit: In some cases these moments are rather straightforward to calculate. Here's an example of computing $E(X^{3/2})$ for $X\sim\text{gamma}(\alpha,1)$:

\begin{eqnarray}
E(X^{3/2}) &=& \int_0^\infty x^{3/2} f(x) dx \\
&=& \frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha)} \int_0^\infty x^{3/2} x^{\alpha-1} e^{-x}  dx\\
&=& \frac{\Gamma(\alpha+3/2)}{\Gamma(\alpha)}\cdot \frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha+3/2)} \int_0^\infty x^{(\alpha+3/2)-1} e^{-x}  dx\\
&=& \Gamma(\alpha+3/2)/\Gamma(\alpha) 
\end{eqnarray}

You can as easily do $E(X^{-1})$ (as long as $\alpha>1$).